# Last four digits of a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If the last four digits of a perfect square are the same, then prove that the four digits must be $0$.

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

A perfect square always has the form $4k$ or $8k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. 
 And you have $10$ cases to check where the digits vary from $0$ to $9$.
They are $\{0000,1111,2222, \ldots 9999\}$

Comment: This is not dispositive without further computation.  For example $7777 \equiv 1 \bmod{8}$.